# Retrieve observable value without an explicit subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this piece of code:

```
this.accounts$ = this.service
  .getAccounts('123Id456')
  .pipe(
    pluck('body'),
  );

this.accounts$.subscribe(accounts => 
  processAccounts(accounts);
);
```

I need the assignment of `this.accounts$` to stay unsubscribed to, because it's used in a template with an the `async` pipe with an `ngFor` loop.

But then for component use, I need to get the accounts to perform some analysis on them.

The above is working, but I was wondering if there is a better way such that I don't have to subscribe explicitly to `accounts$` as shown in the second statement.

I tried adding a `tap(accounts => processAccounts(accounts))` after the `pluck('body'),` but the IDE complained, and also from what I know `tap` is for mainly for debugging purposes.

Is there a way to attach `processAccounts(accounts)` to the first statement?

Comment: "but the IDE complained": what kind of complain? It should work as intended, could you share what you tried exactly?

Comment: Tap() executes side-effects to an observable emission...
So every time the observable emits something, the tap-block will be executed.
As far as i know, you have to subscribe to an observable in order to get its value.
But you can do multiple subscriptions, so you could subscribe in your component and via your async pipe in the *ngFor loop

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-x43pox

Here would be a bit of rxjs-code in stackblitz to support understanding. Tap will be executed before the subscribe block, but if you remove the subscribtion, the pipe (and therefore also the tap-block) will never be executed. Hope this makes it clearer to understand for you :)

Comment: After restarting the IDE the problem disappeared @bagage, thank you for being curious about that. Tapping works nicely and the issue is no longer.

Comment: Thanks for the playground @AndreasRainer, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `tap` operator performs side-effects. You could think of it similar to `map` operator that doesn't affect the notification. But in your case you could actually use the `map` operator to call the function and return a property from the object notification. In fact, the `pluck` operator is also a form of `map` operator that returns only a single specific property and it [internally uses](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/operators/pluck.ts#L52) the `map` operator.

Try the following

```js
this.accounts$ = this.service
  .getAccounts('123Id456')
  .pipe(
    map(res => {
      const accounts = res.body;
      processAccounts(accounts);
      return accounts;
    }),
  );
```

Now the `async` trigger should call the function `processAccounts()`. Although usually functions are member methods, so were you meaning `this.processAccounts()` instead of just `processAccounts()`?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-d. This works of course. I am actually sending `accounts` to an ngrx store, but removed that statement for `processAccounts()` at the last minute for brevity, it should have had a `this.` indeed. After restarting the IDE, I got what I wanted, just slapped a `tap` after the `pluck` and all is good. Your method above is very clear for when one wants to go wild yet still keep the observable unsubscribed to, thanks for that.